# How to make a field validation dependent on a field of another Fieldset in ZF2?

Tags: validation, zend-framework2, zend-validate, zend-form2, zend-form-fieldset

In my form I have some fields, that should be validated depending on some field(-s) in another sub-fieldset of the `Form`:

```
MyForm
- [fieldset] main instanceof WhatEverFieldset
-- [fieldset] foo instanceof FooFieldset
--- [field] field_a
--- [field] field_b
-- [fieldset] bar instanceof BarFieldset
--- [field] field_c
--- [fieldset] xyz instanceof XyzFieldset
---- [field] field_d
-- [fieldset] buz instanceof BuzFieldset
---- [field] field_e
--- [fieldset] xyz instanceof XyzFieldset
---- [field] field_d
```

So there are some validation rules to implement, that effect the fields of multiple fieldsets. E.g.:

- At least `form.main.*.xyz.field_d` has to be set. That means, I cannot define a `required` rule directly in the `XyzFieldset`, since there is a a condition and it for it's located outside of the `XyzFieldset`.
- The value of `form.main.foo.field_a` has to be `grater than` the value of `form.main.bar.field_c`.

**Where / How to define validation rules, that depend on fields' values of other sub-fieldsets of the form?**

Comment: What you are talking about isn't simply form input validation. It's a functionnal validation that answers functionnal needs. Those kind of validation should be processed after input validation, with a custom validator / a validation service / whatever you want.

Comment: @Unex OK, but how to integrate it into the form?